# Redirecting stdout to file nodejs

Tags: node.js, logging, stdout

I've created:

```
var access = fs.createWriteStream('/var/log/node/api.access.log', { flags: 'w' });
```

Then piped:

```
process.stdout.pipe(access);
```

Then tried:

```
console.log("test");
```

And nothing has appeared in /var/log/node/api.access.log. However this way is working:

```
process.stdout.pipe(access).write('test');
```

Could someone explain what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: yeah I am really surprised that you can call pipe on a writable without an error, what is up with that?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I solved this problem the following way:

```
var access = fs.createWriteStream('/var/log/node/api.access.log');
process.stdout.write = process.stderr.write = access.write.bind(access);
```

Of course you can also separate stdout and stderr if you want.

I also would strongly recommend to handle uncaught exceptions:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.error((err && err.stack) ? err.stack : err);
});
```

This will cover the following situations:

- process.stdout.write
- process.stderr.write
- console.log
- console.dir
- console.error
- someStream.pipe(process.stdout);
- throw new Error('Crash');
- throw 'never do this';
- throw undefined;

Comment: Be weary that if you're overwriting `process.stdout.write` you can no longer write to the console.

Comment: Isn't the `uncaughtException` part going to duplicate the same error message in that logging file as stderr is anyway redirected to the file?

Comment: @user36476 No, since node only prints that message if there is no listener for the uncaughtException event.

Answer (score 11):

Checkout `console.Console`, the parent class of the normal `console`.

```
var myLogFileStream = fs.createWriteStream(pathToMyLogFile);

var myConsole = new console.Console(myLogFileStream, myLogFileStream);
```

You can then you use `myConsole.log`, `myConsole.error`, `myConsole.dir`, etc. and write directly to your file.

You can also [monkey patch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_in_monkey-patching) `process.stdout.write` as follows:

```
var fn = process.stdout.write;

function write() {
  fn.apply(process.stdout, arguments);
  myLogFileStream.write.apply(myLogFileStream, arguments);
}

process.stdout.write = write;
```

there are also other options for overwriting `console._stdout` depending on the motivation for logging the `stdout` to a file.

Answer (score 4):

`process.stdout` is a Writable. `pipe` is a method of `Readable`(Cf StreamAPI documentation : https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

You can see the documentation of `process.stdout` here : https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout

It's surprising that you can do `process.stdout.pipe(...);` without any error. But i suppose this call just do nothing. Except returning a new Writable stream binded to stdout (or maybe it returns `process.stdout` itself. There's no specification for that in the documentation).

If you want to redirect stdout to a file, you have many solutions :

- Just use your command line to do that. Windows style : `node myfile.js > api.access.log`.
- Replace the console object by your own object. And you can rewrite console methods.
- I'm not sure, but it may be possible to replace `process.stdout` with your own stream (and you can do whatever you want with this)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is helpful. For now i decided to rewrite console.log method, but hope to find more constructive solution.

Comment: yeah I am really surprised that you can call pipe on a writable without an error, what is up with that?

Comment: According to nodejs [official doc](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) process.stdout is a duplex stream

Comment: @Alex it's not so simple: "It is a net.Socket (which is a Duplex stream) unless fd 1 refers to a file, in which case it is a Writable stream."

Comment: "When Node.js detects that it is being run with a text terminal ("TTY") attached, [`process.stdin`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) will, by default, be initialized as an instance of `tty.ReadStream` and both [`process.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) and [`process.stderr`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stderr) will, by default be instances of `tty.WriteStream`." —[TTY | Node.js Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_tty)

Comment: Just wanted to add that child process takes (pipes in) its readableStream argument as process.stdout (i.e. parent.stdout) which might seem a bit confusing but this relevant relationship parent to child makes writable to be accepted as readable tho !

Answer (score 2):

@user3173842
for the reply on 
I solved this problem the following way:

```
var access = fs.createWriteStream('/var/log/node/api.access.log');
process.stdout.write = process.stderr.write = access.write.bind(access);
```

you do understand that `process.stdout` continues after `process.on('exit')` and therefore the `fs.WriteStream` closes after with `process.stdout`, according to
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7606

so now the question remains, if the developer desired to have the `fs.Writestream.write()` return to its normal functionality and when `fs.Writestream.end` is called the writestream closes. How would the developer go about doing  this I did

```
a_l = asyncify_listener
p_std_stream_m is a process stream manager object

p_std_stream_m.std_info.p_stdout_write = process.stdout.write   

process.stdout.write = w_stream.write.bind(w_stream)

process.once('beforeExit', a_l(   p_std_stream_m.handler,process.stdout,w_stream   )   )       

     where in the 'beforeExit' event listener I did
process.stdout.write = p_std_stream_m.std_info.p_stdout_write

w_stream.end()
```

It works  and you use the once method because the `process.stdout` seems to do a lot of work 
   at this time.
Is this good practice, would you do this or what would you do in this situation
anyone can feel free to reply.

Comment: Also try stream.pipleline() hopefully at process.exit() process.stdout lets it go

Answer (score 2):

Originally based on @Anatol-user3173842 answer

But in my case I needed to hook the stdout & stderr and also write into a file.

So for those who need to keep the normal stdout behaviour in addition to writing into the file. Use the following.

For non-errors:

```
// stdout logging hook
const stdoutWrite0 = process.stdout.write;
process.stdout.write = (args) => { // On stdout write
  CustomLogger.writeToLogFile('log', args); // Write to local log file
  args = Array.isArray(args) ? args : [args]; // Pass only as array to prevent internal TypeError for arguments
  return stdoutWrite0.apply(process.stdout, args);
};
```

For errors:

```
// stderr logging hook
const stderrWrite0 = process.stderr.write;
process.stderr.write = (args) => { // On stderr write
  CustomLogger.writeToLogFile('error', args); // Write to local error file
  args = Array.isArray(args) ? args : [args]; // Pass only as array to prevent internal TypeError for arguments
  return stderrWrite0.apply(process.stderr, args);
};

// uncaught exceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  CustomLogger.writeToLogFile('error', ((err && err.stack) ? err.stack : err));
});
```

Here is the `CustomLogger` code, where I also separate the log files by date:

```
export class CustomLogger {

 static LOGS_DIR = 'location-of-my-log-files';

 private static logDailyName(prefix: string): string {
   const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g, '_');
   return `${CustomLogger.LOGS_DIR}/${prefix}_${date}.log`;
 }

 private static writeToLogFile(prefix, originalMsg) {
   const timestamp   = Date.now();
   const fileName    = this.logDailyName(prefix);
   const logMsg      = prepareForLogFile(originalMsg);
   fs.appendFileSync(fileName, `${timestamp}\t${logMsg}\n\n`);
   return originalMsg;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of a logger class that redirects `stdout`, `stderr` and exceptions to a file, while still writting everything to the console:

```
class Logger {
  #log_stream
  #stdout_write
  #stderr_write
  constructor(path) {
    this.#log_stream = fs.createWriteStream(path, { flags: 'a' })
    this.#stdout_write = process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout)
    this.#stderr_write = process.stderr.write.bind(process.stderr)
    process.stdout.write = this.stdout_write.bind(this)
    process.stderr.write = this.stderr_write.bind(this)
    process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
      console.error((err && err.stack) ? err.stack : err)
    })
  }
  stdout_write(buffer) {
    this.#log_stream.write(buffer)
    this.#stdout_write(buffer)
  }
  stderr_write(buffer) {
    this.#log_stream.write(buffer)
    this.#stderr_write(buffer)
  }
}

const logger = new Logger('example.log')
```