# How can I print log to file by using js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

mongodb load js

load(myjs.js)

in myjs.js have the print("this is a test log");

how can I print this log into log.txt file?

Comment: Does this answers your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719923/redirecting-stdout-to-file-nodejs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting stdout to file nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719923/redirecting-stdout-to-file-nodejs)